# Read all keys from a dictionary which in plist using plistbuddy

Tags: ios, dictionary, plist

I want to read all the keys from a dictionary which in plist using plistbuddy and push the value into an array.
I knew that the below utility help to read plist.
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy

So far I'm hard coding the key to get value.
Eg: theKey = "selva"

So i write below code to get value of above key

```
val=$(function_stringFields "${theFile}" "${theKey}" "${index}")
```

(`function_stringFields` is a custom method.)

Is there anyway to achieve the same.

Comment: @Whoever replied, First i should admit that i'm 2days old to shell script. I'm trying to understand what you have answered.

Comment: while the questions is specific to plistBuddy - people may want to checkout swift scripting https://gist.github.com/johndpope/953b0f961a6c77ffbb01c5d5a5baa04a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to getting this done is the print option for plistbuddy.
Without arguments it will print out all lines.

Here is a small script that will load an array of keys and and array of values.

Success of this will really depend on what kind of tree you may have built in the plist.  If it is flat you will be happier.  This example also does not account for spaces in the values (they would be removed).

```js
LINES=`/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy FrameworkList.plist -c print | grep = | tr -d ' '`

COUNTER=0

for PLIST_ITEMS in $LINES;
do
  KEY[${COUNTER}]=`echo $PLIST_ITEMS | cut -d= -f1`
  VALUE[${COUNTER}]=`echo $PLIST_ITEMS | cut -d= -f2`
  COUNTER=${COUNTER}+1
done
```

Comment: If i echo $LINES, Statement comes without any space. Eg. Actual plist statement is key as "sog" and value as "Stack overflow is a good blog". but result of @LINES is "sog"  and value as "Stackoverflowisagoodblog"

Answer (score 3):

```
plist_file=/Applications/iTunes.app/Contents/Info.plist
keys=(`/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print "$plist_file" | perl -lne 'print $1 if /^    (\S*) =/'`)
```

This will create an array `keys` that holds all the top-level keys. All it's doing is looking for output that starts with four spaces and then a key and then "=".